# How to allow a team member to access my Google Cloud Platform account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Google's Play Console allows to invite team members who can manage apps and do changes in behalf of the owner of the apps. This is useful to do work for a customer without requiring him to share his account login information.

Is the same available for Google's [Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/)? I'd like to create a project, enable various APIs for Google Maps and receive the API key in behalf of my customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Cloud Platform Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard) is a widget that allows to add people to the current project, nice:

[image: Project info widget]

Answer (score 1):

In addition of adding a team member into your project, you would need to grant them access to the resources that you are allowing them to use. Check out this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access).

Keeping the principle of least privilege in mind, [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/dont-get-pwned-practicing-the-principle-of-least-privilege) are five practical tips to minimize the surface area of exposed resources on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) and defend against some common attacks.